# Change the position of a table in page using CSS

Tags: css

I have a table and it is at the end of the page:

```
<table class="fes-display-field-table fes-submission-form-display-field-table">
</table>
```

Now I want move that table to between:

```
<h2 class="section-title"><span>Giới thiệu về Dịch vụ</span></h2>
TABLE HERE
<article id="post-8306" class="post-8306 type-download status-publish format-standard hentry...>
```

Is there any way to do it with CSS?
Here is my css file: https://jsfiddle.net/wcq1ft3k/

Comment: Do you want to only change the position visually, or reorder the elements in HTML? The latter is possible only with JavaScript.

Comment: i want to change the position visually. I actually cant reorder the elements in HTML.

Comment: Then you have to post relevant CSS code here. Please create a code snippet.

Comment: sorry, i added the css file. Could you please have a look?

Answer (score 0):

this is what you want. you have to give `position` property for your table style.I only concerned about position your table. try this code. then change the values of `left` and `top`. think your table class name is `mytable`

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
  .mytable{
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    left: 300px;
  }
</style>
<body>

  <table class="mytable">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
      <th style="width:200px; border-right:1px solid black;">one</th>
      <th style="width:200px">two</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td>detail one</th>
      <td>detail two</th>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>



</body>
</html>
```

hope this will help to you.